# Cannot get L.control.coordinate to work properly

Tags: javascript, leaflet, plugins

I am trying to make a map modal with Leaflets that displays the lat./lng. coordinates in a box when the user clicks on the desired point. I got the popup given in the Leaflets tutorial to work fine and now I am trying to use the Controls.Coordinates plugin. I currently using the the Coordinates Control plugin, but I keep getting errors like `NumberFormatter.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined` (Note: I have the Control.Coordinates.js installed) or `Uncaught TypeError: L.Control.Coordinates is not a constructor.` I think there must be a problem with how I have my plugin path or perhaps the javascript. Any ideas?

```
<head>
<title>Create Job</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"     
href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.19.1/mapbox-gl.css'  
rel='stylesheet' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./src/util/NumberFormatter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./src/Control.Coordinates.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/Control.Coordinates.css"/>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.19.1/mapbox-gl.js'>   
</script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   
integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="  
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And here is the javascript part. The problem seems to occur when I declare `var c = L.Control.Coordinates()`:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div id="mapid"></div>
    <script>
      var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([38.410, -78.13], 2);

      var mainLayer = 
      L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?
      access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a  
        href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a 
        href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, 
        Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 20,
        id: '<myid>',
        accessToken:<mytoken>


    }).addTo(mymap);

    var c = new L.Control.Coordinates();  // you can send options to the 
    constructor if you want to, otherwise default values are used

    c.addTo(mymap);

    map.on('click', function(e) {
    c.setCoordinates(e);

    });  
    //var popup = L.popup();

    //function onMapClick(e) {
      //popup
        //.setLatLng(e.latlng)
        //.setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
        //.openOn(mymap);
        //}

        //mymap.on('click', onMapClick);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic script tag order issue.

Make sure you load the Leaflet library (and possibly the Mapbox one too) **before** the associated plugins. Otherwise, the latter will not be able to find Leaflet definition and do their work.

When your issue is very programming-related, feel free to ask on Stack Overflow, you would probably receive an answer much more quickly.

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly. One side-note: I now have a box with coordinates showing in my map. What I want to do now, is grab those coordinates and populate a box in the header. I want to be able to data bind them and hopefully send them back to a database or have them shoot to a json file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Feel free to open a new question for this request. I would also suggest switching to Stack Overflow, as it is very programming-related and less GIS specific. I am sure plenty people will be able to help you. Pay attention to give technical details of what you want to achieve, otherwise if people do not understand, they will not spend time for you.